# Android SwitchCompat play animation on toggle() or setChecked()

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I added a SwitchCompat to my Drawernavigation in Android.

First I set the item's actionlayout to my switchlayout.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
app:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
app:switchPadding="16dp" />
```

Now I'm trying to change the Buttons checkedstate in my Code, I'm trying `switchCopmatObj.toggle()` and also tried     `switchCompatObj.setChecked(!switchCompatObj.isChecked())`

But it only changes the Color of the Switch, but doesn't play the animation where the Switch moves from one side to the other. How do I play this animation from my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue. It seems that *SwitchCompat* is broken on this point. **setChecked()** calls the animator that should update the thumb drawable but the **onAnimationEnd** is never called.

Meanwhile after many tries faking the touch events send to the *SwitchCompat*, I found an ugly workaround : instead of calling **setChecked()**, I remove the item from the menu and add it again :

```
// Update toggle state
mDrawerView.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.drawer_menu_availability);
final SwitchCompat toggle = (SwitchCompat) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.drawer_menu_item_availability, null);
toggle.setChecked(mAvailable);
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> toggleAvailability());
final MenuItem added = mDrawerView.getMenu().add(R.id.drawer_menu_group_actions, R.id.drawer_menu_availability, Menu.FIRST, text);
added.setActionView(toggle);
```

This however forces you to :

- have an id for the menu group where your menu item is located
- use **android:orderInCategory** to order your menu items so that your item goes back to the same place when adding it back.

Hope this helps.

EDIT :  This does not play the animation but at least the thumb is in the right place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I hope google fixes this asap.